# TouchSwipe Mobile Menu

Tags: html, mobile, transition, touchswipe

Please i need help. My intention is to develop a mobile application with the following details:
1. Swipe-able menu from left to right.
2. When the body is menu is disappears
3. Fixed Header with logo on every page 
4. Multiple Html page called from the menu on click
5. Transitions between pages

Comment: What have you got already? What problems are you having?

Comment: i am looking at this design on this site http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Mobile-Off-screen-Push-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS3/.          In addition to this, i want a swipe event from left to right for the menu in a mobile phone

Comment: So far your question isn't clear. Try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks for your response. Actually this is a sample code .